# What does the + in this place means?

Tags: javascript

I have problem with understanding this code. I know what it do, but I dont understand the "+" after return.

```js
function descendingOrder(n) {
    return +n.toString().split('').sort().reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: its's a number. for example: 12345

Comment: can be a string. for example: '12345'